# MySQL: Replace result of first query with the result of 2nd query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

**Table 1:timetable**

```
monday  tuesday  wednesday
------  -------  ---------
   18     15         2
   10      8         6
```

**Table 2:subjects**

```
subject_id  subject_name  
----------  ------------
   18           maths 
   10          history
    8          english
```

Result should look like:

```
    monday   tuesday   wednesday  
    ------- --------  ---------
    maths     phy       phy
   history  history     phy
   english    chem      phy
```

**How do I do this ?**

Comment: I didn't get the logic, but [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) is what you should look at.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ms.subject_name as moday,
       ts.subject_name as tuesday,
       ws.subject_name as wednesday
FROM timetable t
INNER JOIN subjects ms ON t.monday = ms.subject_id
INNER JOIN subjects ts ON t.tuesday = ts.subject_id
INNER JOIN subjects ws ON t.wednesday = ws.subject_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT SM.subject_name AS [monday]
    ,ST.subject_name AS [tuesday]
    ,SW.subject_name AS [wednesday]
FROM timetable T
INNER JOIN subjects SM ON SM.subject_id = T.monday
INNER JOIN subjects ST ON ST.subject_id = T.tuesday
INNER JOIN subjects SW ON SW.subject_id = T.wednesday
```

Hope this will help you.